# Why does gsub in Ruby one liner out hash refs?

Tags: ruby

Below you see my input file. Why does it output hash refs and not put the input without the `---`?

```
$ cat a
---
Main:
  aaah: Administrator
  aacp: Administrator
  a868: User
  1585: User
  5053: User
  5423: User


/tmp$ 
$ ruby -pe 'gsub("---\n", '')' a 
#<Enumerator:0x00005e335d1d08>#<Enumerator:0x00005e335d1b78>#<Enumerator:0x00005e335d1a38>#<Enumerator:0x00005e335d1920>#<Enumerator:0x00005e335d1808>#<Enumerator:0x00005e335d16f0>#<Enumerator:0x00005e335d15d8>#<Enumerator:0x00005e335d14c0>#<Enumerator:0x00005e335d13a8>#<Enumerator:0x00005e335d1290>
```

Comment: Check your quotes, you have to use `""`

Comment: ... which means `$ ruby -pe 'gsub("---\n", "")' a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command needs the correct quotations.
Should look something like this:

`$ ruby -pe 'gsub("---\n", "")' a` 
 or 
`$ ruby -pe "gsub('---\n', '')" a`